# unable to start git gui because of tcl version conflict

Tags: git, tcl, git-gui

When I try to run the git-gui an error message pops up that claims to have a version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.5, need exactly 8.6.4.
But when I request the installed tcl patchlevel from a tclsh it says 8.6.4.

Can anyone figure out why git thinks to have a wrong version?

I use the latest git version for windows 2.8.1

thanks

Comment: Most code doesn't use exact version matching, but the exception is Tcl's own startup code which ***MUST*** match the library version. Something's going wrong there.

Comment: Yes, that was also my guess. But the strange thing is that I have installed the exactly same version.